# Include only select localizations in application build

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, localization

I am working on a Mac App in Xcode. Eventually, I plan to add a few localizations to languages other than English. I have already started, and I now have localizations for French and Czech in Xcode.

However, I don't have a few other things ready in those languages, and therefore, for now, I decided to submit my app to the Mac App Store using only the English localization.

Is there a way to tell Xcode to only include the English version in the .app it builds? I would rather not have to delete / re-add the localizations manually to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to do that using Xcode but you can simplify your life by playing with version control system. For example, create a branch for your localisation files that you don't want to include (that may as well include Xcode project file as they are listed there), and do not merge it into the main project until it is done.

Comment: I've just got one more idea - create a copy of the target, and exclude localizations that you don't want. So you'll run one target to test new locales, and another one submit to app store. That way sources and stuff will be the same, and no branching will be involved.